# Using `call()` function returns false when trying to call function of a smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-invocation

I'm creating a test contract for calling external ones & ran into an weird issue with `call()` where it just keeps returning false. Being new to solidity, I'm not sure what is failing it. Here is the following code.

```
contract Main {
    event Response(bool successful, bytes data);

    function testCallSetInt(uint v) external {
        address helloContract = 0x809d550fca64d94Bd9F66E60752A544199cfAC3D;
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = helloContract.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("set(uint)", v)
        );
        console.log(success);
        emit Response(success, data);
    }
}
```

The deployed contract I'm trying to call is definied as such

```
contract HelloWorld {
  uint storedValue;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedValue = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedValue;
  }
}
```

When I log success I only get false & no other indicators as to why this is failing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you need to use full name for types.
Just use uint256 instead of uint like this:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = helloContract.call(
      abi.encodeWithSignature("set(uint256)", v)
  );
```

and this should work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what OliverD said, this works in Remix:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract Main {
    event Response(bool successful, bytes data);

    function testCallSetInt(uint v) external {
        address helloContract = 0x809d550fca64d94Bd9F66E60752A544199cfAC3D;
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = helloContract.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("set(uint256)", v)
        );
        require(success, "call failed");
        emit Response(success, data);
    }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863261/solidity-abi-encodewithsignature-did-not-work-with-diffienet-parameters